# Disable Windows Key Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, windows-registry

The header says most of it. I'm trying to find a way to disable the windows key either through GPO, local policy, or an edit in registry, but Google has been less than helpful.

Comment: [How to enable or disable the keyboard Windows key](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/216893) ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but none of those things worked on my machine.

Comment: Open regedit.

On the Windows menu, click HKEY_LOCAL_ MACHINE on Local Machine.

Double-click the System\CurrentControlSet\Control folder, and then click the Keyboard Layout folder.

On the Edit menu, click Add Value, type in Scancode Map, click REG_BINARY as the Data Type, and then click OK.

Type 00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000 in the Data field, and then click OK.

Close Registry Editor and restart the computer.

Comment: @vembutech this is the same instruction that has been posted here already, it didn't work for me, but thanks anyways.

Comment: One thing we will notice, specially in these days of "working from home" is that the mapping will not be seen when doing a remote desktop connection since the mappings are for a local keyboard only. This took me a while to figure out since I am doing RD from a Mac computer. The solution was Autohotkey as others mention.

Answer (score 1):

Like CJ1992 says (I could not comment unfortunately hence new post), but the AutoHotkey syntax now seems to be (it might be that I use 1.1.30.00 - August 22, 2018 version):

```
LWin::return
RWin::return
```

quoted from [AutoHotkey site](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Override.htm)

Answer (score 1):

If using [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), the following script disables the ability for the <kbd>Win</kbd> key to activate the Start Menu, while still allowing its use as a modifier:

```
~LWin::
~RWin::Send {Blind}{vkFF}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of disabling the Windows Key as seen on [this page](http://www.pcgamer.com/how-to-disable-the-windows-key/)

Option 1: Registry Editor

> 1. Click Start, click Run, type regedt32, and then click OK.
> 2. On the Windows menu, click HKEY_LOCAL_ MACHINE on Local Machine.
> 3. Double-click the System\CurrentControlSet\Control folder, and then click the Keyboard Layout folder.
> 4. On the Edit menu, click Add Value, type in Scancode Map, click REG_BINARY as The Data Type, and then click OK.
> 5. Type 00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000 in the Data field, and then click OK.
> 6. Close Registry Editor and restart the computer.

Option 2: AutoHotKey

> 1. Download AutoHotKey from http://www.autohotkey.com/
> 2. Run it, then right click on its icon in the taskbar.Select 'Edit This Script' and it'll open the default script in Notepad
> 3. Somewhere between the comments (which are marked with semi-colons) add the following:
>
>    ~LWin Up:: return
>
>    ~RWin Up:: return
> 4. Now just save the file, right click on AutoHotkey again, and select 'Reload This Script.'

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help. Could not seem to be able to do it for the life of me :D

Answer (score 0):

Try [sharpkeys](https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), it's like a Graphical interface to the registry.  Whatever change you make is written to the registry, so no daemons, no background processes. just make the change, log off and log in.  features include:

re-map keys
disable keys

and it's open source software, and it's tiny.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to successfully do this, just download the following .bat file and right-click on it and run it as administrator, your computer will restart and after you login, you can hit the windows key, WIN+R, etc won't work.

The Bat files:

disablewinkey.bat: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vcQejf7bO21BLJYaYW_FhtZ9nShv9gX4/view

If you change you're mind and want your windows key working again, then just download the following:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Xm-16l0yyZFqGCTcMlcQ5bSGXu_o2jZf/view

If you're wondering what the bat file does to disable windows key, it simply adds a new binary key called "Scancode map" and resarts your computer.

```
    reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /t REG_BINARY /d 00000000000000000300000000005BE000005CE000000000 && shutdown /r -t 00
```

To enable the windows key, the bat file simply deletes the binary value and restarts your computer.

```
    reg delete "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /v "Scancode Map" /f && shutdown /r -t 00
```

Comment: You can check out the code on my GitHub, https://github.com/Booooozo/Disable-Windows-Key